# Getting started with Facebook's Open Graph

Tags: facebook

I've been looking around for resources on learning to work with and use Open Graph by Facebook.  I have their documentation page, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/, but am curious if there are any renowned online resources that other Facebook developers have been using?

I'm all for documentation, but am most interested in a comprehensive example to give me an idea for how Open Graph applications look & feel.

Thanks,

Comment: Good question. I'm in the same position as your are. From what I can tell there have been massive changes to Facebook recently and basically all of the documentation on Facebook is outdated. Everything seems to be incredibly complicated at the moment for Facebook app newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook provides some examples (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples).

And the documentation page is up to date (for now :) )

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has an [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) page, and there's some information available at http://www.opengraphprotocol.org.

For automated feedback, Facebook also offers a tool called [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/). You provide it with a URL, and it will show you what Open Graph data is found on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog](http://lynnlangit.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/getting-started-with-facebook-open-graph-api/), created a deck and 4 short screencasts on my experience starting with the Facebook Open Graph API - HTH